# How to decode a base64 SVG file and use it as a Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, angular-components, angular-template

I would like to convert a base64 encoded SVG image into an Angular template with the extension .svg, for example my-template.component.svg.

I get the base64 encoded svg through an API call in the following form:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iREVWSUNFX01BUF8tX09wZW5lZF9jb3B5IiBkYXRhLW5...
```

This should become a normal SVG file, which I would like to use as a template. So the content of `my-template.component.svg` should look like this:

```
<svg width = "100" height = "100">
   <circle cx = "50" cy = "50" r = "40" stroke = "green" stroke-width = "4" fill = "yellow" />
   ...
</svg>
```

Otherwise I cannot manipulate the base64 encoded SVG with CSS, since the selectors are not available in the DOM.

Currently the returned value from the API call is used like this:

```
<img id ="img" [src]="api-url +'/path/to/svg/file.svg'" />
```

So the src attribute of the img tag becomes:

```
<img id="img" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iREVWSUNFX01BUF8tX09wZW5lZF9jb3B5IiBkYXRhLW5..." />
```